# "Compare the speeds of" or "Compare the speed of"?

Tags: nouns, grammatical-number, uncountable-nouns

What is the correct expression:

"Compare the speeds of the cars" or "Compare the speed of the cars"?

Comment: Do all the cars have the same speed, or do different cars have different speeds?

Comment: They probably have different speeds. We do not know before we compare them.

Comment: If you look on the internet, many of the first hits for "compare the speed of" continue "X and Y". And some of these seem to be in scholarly articles. I think it's another example of usage trumping strict logic; certailyy 'compare the speeds of X and Y' is grammato-logical, and must be considered acceptable. // With 'compare the strength/s of the men', I'd assume different readings (physical strength for the singular-form noun; character pluses for the plural form).

Comment: @Peter A leading question if ever there was one. But leading to the idiomatic answer?

Comment: Depends on what follows "of".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be 'Compare the speeds of the cars' as in this case, you are measuring each individual speed of each car and comparing. As you are measuring multiple quantities, the noun 'speed' is pluralised into 'speeds'.

Comment: "Compare the speed of the cars in the Indy 500 to the speed of Earth orbiting the Sun"